# Input data to website and extract result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, data-extraction

I'm hoping someone can guide me with this little project.

I have a list of addresses in an excel file and would like to paste the addresses  (can be zipcodes) individually into the website linked below and extract the Long/Lat coordinates and paste them next to the address in the same excel file.

Is this possible? I'm assuming I would use a combination of python, beautifulsoup? I read somewhere about mechanize. Your help would be appreciated.

website:https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned website uses the Google Maps API to convert an address to coordinates (known as geocoding). To be able to use the Google Maps API, you will need an API key
You can follow the instructions [here](https://www.wpgmaps.com/documentation/creating-a-google-maps-api-key/#create) on how to obtain an API key.

Once you have done that you need to install the `googlemaps` Python package to be able to use the API:
`pip install googlemaps`

The following code converts an address to coordinates and prints out at which coordinates the given address is at:

```
import googlemaps

key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway' #  Google's address

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=key)

# Convert the given address to coordinates. You can use gmaps.reverse_geocode((lat, lng)) 
# to convert the coordinates back to an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(address)

lat = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] #  Get the latitude
lng = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] #  Get the longitude

print(address, 'is at', (lat, lng))
```

Comment: Aaron - thank you for this guide, I've followed it and it works! Is it possible for python to pull the address list from an excel file and load the lat/lng back into the same file accordingly? I would hate to manually type all the addresses in on a monthly basis haha.

Comment: @D-Ru Have a look at the `pandas` module, specifically the `read_excel` method. It supports reading data from excel files which can then be used in your program.